# How to add new property to JCR node through CQ.extjs?

Tags: extjs, aem

I need to add a new property to a existing node in JCR:content from javascript(ExtJS).

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. Can you post some code which you have tried ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use HTTP POST method (via AJAX) and [Sling POST servlet](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html), like:

```
CQ.HTTP.post('/content/path/to/my/page/jcr:content', null, { newProperty: '123' });
```

Comment: instead of the `null` you can use a error handling function, i.e. `CQ.HTTP.post('/content/path/to/my/page/jcr:content', function(options, success, response){if (!success){alert('Could not save data');}},{ newProperty: '123' });`

Comment: Hi Tomek, Can you please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745246/how-to-validate-a-field-using-cq-http-post-method-in-adobe-cq5/29754840#29754840