# How can I make a new jcr:content node with Extjs?

Tags: extjs, aem

Some pages in my CQ5.5 application are being made with no 'jcr:content' node. Since the node does not exist the properties of these particular pages do not exist and cannot be fixed by users. I want to add a button that will allow a user to add the node if it is missing. I have been able to add a button "Fix Properties" that has a custom function attached that retrieves the existing node and I am able to check for the existence of the jcr:content node. I cannot find documentation anywhere on how to make a node from scratch. I figured this would be a common thing but there is very little to find about it.

I found this documentation for Nodes in general and most of the functions work but so far no dice: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.data.Node

and so far have this function. Each attempt was done separately:

```
CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.createProperties = function() {
   var path = this.getCurrentPath();
   var tree = CQ.Ext.getCmp(this.id + "-tree");
   //var nodet = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedNode(); //gets the selected node
   //nodet.childNodes[i] skips over jcr:content nodes
   var nodej = CQ.Util.eval(path + '.2.json'); //am currently using this to get the node data instead
   if(typeof nodej['jcr:content'] == 'undefined')  //If the jcr:content node does not exist
   {
     //Attempt 1: 
       nodej['jcr:content'] = new CQ.wcm.Node({ 
           jcr:primaryType: "cq:PageContent",
           jcr:title: "title"});
     //Attempt 2: 
       nodej['jcr:content'] = new Node({  //Note no 'CQ.wcm'
           jcr:primaryType: "cq:PageContent",
           jcr:title: "title"});
     //Attempt 3:
     nodej.appendChild( new CQ.wcm.Node({ 
           jcr:primaryType: "cq:PageContent",
           jcr:title: "title"}));
     //Attempt 4:
     nodej.appendChild( new CQ.wcm.Node({ 
           Name : "jcr:content",              
           jcr:primaryType: "cq:PageContent",
           jcr:title: "title"}));
    }

};
```

None of the above attempts do anything but it is the closest thing I could think of.

I did find this question: [How to add new property to JCR node through CQ.extjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398657/how-to-add-new-property-to-jcr-node-through-cq-extjs) but it did nothing visible and it is also about adding to an existing node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your attempts modify the Javascript object `nodej`, but there is no mechanism to reflect these changes in the repository automatically. That's why the changes were not saved. In order to create new node, you need to send a HTTP POST request:

```
CQ.HTTP.post(path + "/jcr:content", null, {
  "jcr:primaryType" : "cq:PageContent",
  "jcr:title" : "Title"
});
```

This request will by handled by the [Sling framework](http://sling.apache.org/) (more precisely, by the [SlingPostServlet](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html)), which will create a new resource.

Sidenote: please notice that you need to quote key name in the Javascript associative arrays if it contains a special character, like `:`. Therefore, following code will work:

```
console.log({
    "jcr:primaryType" : "cq:PageContent"
});
```

but this one will cause a syntax error:

```
console.log({
    jcr:primaryType : "cq:PageContent"
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It wasn't working for a little bit but I had a separate bug that came about from a different test. It is all good now.